# Load XML in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to load up an XML document in MVC in the "HomeController"

I want this document to load up in everything under the /Home/ directory so have my class:

```
public HomeController()
        {  }
```

And inside this I have the code that I want to connect to the XML with:

```
//Now set up the config xml read
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"));
        XmlNodeList settings = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/settings");
        XmlNodeList defaults = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("default");
        foreach (XmlNode node in defaults)
        {
            string def_WebPageName = node["WebPageName "].InnerText;
        }
```

Structure of the XML:

```
<settings>
<defaults>
  <WebPageName>blah</WebPageName>
</defaults>
```

I cannot seem to locate theXML file, keep getting a "Object set to null reference" error

Comment: What line causes the null ref exception?  If xmldoc.Load couldn't find the file you would get some kind of IO exception not a null ref.

Comment: maybe the Path is not correct.

xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"));

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 29:             //Now set up the config xml read
Line 30:             XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
Line 31:             xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"));

Comment: using the debugger, try to find what is null. If required, refactor the code to use a variable like this : `var filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"); xmldoc.Load(filePath);` in order to check if the file is actually found, also, which line is the 29th ?

Comment: For some reason, httpContext is null when I inspect it. line 29 is just a comment. "//Now set up the config xml read"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Web app you get somthing like http://yoursite/Content/settings.xml. Check whether this file path exists on the web server. If it is a WinForms app use ExecutionPath or Environment variables to get the path you need.

You should also use something like `if(File.Exists(yourFilePathHere))`

Comment: Just checked from the browser, and the file is accessible. I think it may have something to do with how I am calling the file?

Comment: So try to use a stream from webrequest instead of the string.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"));
```

try with only

```
xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/settings.xml"));
```